# Last a out of b updates were of same kind

Tags: javascript

I wanted to know what would be an **efficient** way to achieve this in javascript:

every second I update a variable X (X=0 at start)
updates are +1 or -1 only. (X+=1 or X-=1)

I want to take an action if 5 out of the last 7 updates were negative.

function check should perform the required computation to determine if last 5/7 updates were negative.

I've tried using an array to push +1 on incr() and 0 on decr() and calculate sum of last 7 elements but that is not efficient at all.

```js
let x = 0;

function start() {
  window.setInterval(() => {
    Math.round(Math.random()) ? incr() : decr();
  }, 1000)
}

function incr() {
  x += 1;
  check()
}

function decr() {
  x -= 1;
  check()
}

function check() {
  console.log(x);
}

start()
```

Comment: And SO is not for questions like this: [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users), [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could take an array of the increments/decrements and count the values.

```js
function start() {
  function incr() {
    last7.unshift(1);
    if (last7.length > 7) last7.length = 7;
    x += 1;
    check();
  }

  function decr() {
    last7.unshift(-1);
    if (last7.length > 7) last7.length = 7;
    x -= 1;
    check();
  }

  function check() {
    if (last7.reduce((s, v) => s + (v === -1), 0) >= 5) console.log(x, '*****');
    else console.log(x);
  }

  let x = 0;
  const last7 = [];

  window.setInterval(() => {
    Math.round(Math.random()) ? incr() : decr();
  }, 1000)
}

start();
```

A slightly shorter approach

```js
function start() {
    function update(value) {
        x += value;
        last7.unshift(value);
        if (last7.length > 7) last7.length = 7;
        check();
    }

    function check() {
        const count = last7.reduce((s, v) => s + (v === -1), 0);
        if (count >= 5) console.log(x, '*' + count);
        else console.log(x, count);
    }

    let x = 0;
    const last7 = [];

    window.setInterval(() => update(Math.round(Math.random()) || -1), 1000)
}

start();
```

Comment: And this is why the accepted answer with _"I've tried using an array to push +1 on incr() and 0 on decr() and calculate sum of last 7 elements but that is not efficient at all."_ ?

Answer (score 0):

Maintain last 7 numbers as sliding window. Using `Math.sign` to decide on -1 or 1.

```js
const win = [];

function start() {
  window.setInterval(() => {
    const value = Math.sign(Math.random() - 0.5);
    win.push(value);
    if (win.length > 7) {
      win.shift();
    }
    check();
  }, 1000);
}

function check() {
  const criteria = win.filter((x) => x === -1).length >= 5;
  criteria && console.log("Yeah, last 5/7 are negatives");
  
  console.log('Last 7: ', win.join(''));
}

start();
```